# Use of * in a printf statement

Tags: c

Can anyone explain me the logic behind these outputs?I guess here `*` is used as a suppression character but I can't figure out the outputs.

```
main()
{
char *s="hello world";
int i=7;
printf("%.*%s",s);
}
```

Output: %s

If you replace the printf statement as `printf("%,*%s",s)` then your output will be ,*hello world???

Comment: Your question says `scanf` but your code says `printf`.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry I wrote scanf by mistake,it will be printf.I have edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The printf format string `"%.*%s"` is invalid. The `*` character is not treated as a conversion suppressing specifier, but rather as the argument to the `.` character which specifies a precision.

Compare with something like:

```
printf("%.*s", 3, str);
```

where the `*` takes the next argument (3) as the precision field (which has a particular meaning for strings), and then the `s` takes the string. Since the `3` is a constant, this is equivalent to hard-coding it in the format string:

```
printf("%.3s", str);
```

So what you have here is is `%.*` which looks like the start of a conversion with a variable precision field. It will consume the `s` argument and treat it as an `int`, which is undefined behavior.

Even if the next argument were actually an int, then what happens next, is that the `%` character which follows the `*` variable precision is not a valid conversion specifier. Or, rather, it is a valid conversion specifier, as part of the `%%` conversion. But the `%%` sequence for codifying a literal `%` does not support optional material in betweeen the two characters. ISO 9899:1999 says (of the `%` specifier) that "the complete conversion specification shall be `%%`."

It also says that "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined."  A `%%` specification where you have material in between like a width or precision field, is invalid because it violates the explicitly stated requirement that "the complete conversion specification shall be `%%`."

Comment: Well, but I don't think a format string like `"%.*%s"` is **invalid**, it's just not what people usually want, but it's **totally compatible** with the ANSI C standard. Sorry I can't find out in which section this was specified for now.

Comment: My copy of ISO9899:1999 says that "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined".  The consequences of fumbling a format string are grave. :)

Comment: Yes you're right about it, plz check my update on my answer. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here your formated string has been interpreted as two parts `"%.*%"` and `"s"`, where the former one is an 'escaped' percent sign with specified maximum width(this is what here your `*` does) of value of pointer `s`. Try removing the 2nd percent sign first.

Sorry I think I shall try this for you first, but it's currently inconvenient for me..

**EDITED:**

Yes, to get what you want you shall write like this:

```
// here width is a customized value you pass to specify the maximum width of string 
printf("%.*s", width, s); 

// and this would give "hello worl" as its output. notice the missing "d"
printf("%.*s", 10, s);
```

**AGAIN EDITED:**

Plz check [the reference manual of `printf`](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html#printf)

> Width:
>   The width of the field is specified here with a decimal value. If the value is not large enough to fill the width, then the rest of the field is padded with spaces (unless the 0 flag is specified). If the value overflows the width of the field, then the field is expanded to fit the value. If a * is used in place of the width specifer, then the next argument (which must be an int type) specifies the width of the field. Note: when using the * with the width and/or precision specifier, the width argument comes first, then the precision argument, then the value to be converted.

**YET AGAIN EDITED:**

@Kaz is right about the standard. See ISO-IEC-9899_1990 (on page 137 of edition 2):

> % Matches a single %: no conversion or assignment occurs. The complete conversion
>   specification shall be %%

So inserting any other conversion specifier between the two percent sign would cause an undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, your first `printf()` statement is ill-formed, since it does not provide an int argument to the `*` modifier, and the use of precision to the `%` conversion specifier is undefined. In your case, it seems your C implementation is ignoring the precision, so your print statement is equivalent to: `printf("%%s",s);`, which should result in the output:

```
%s
```

(`%%` converts to a `%` in the output).

For your second `printf()` statement, it is again ill-formed, since you provide an invalid conversion specifier, namely `,`. The behavior of using this specifier results in undefined behavior. Your system seems to output the bad specifier, then outputs the `*`, then processes the `%s` which outputs your string.

```
,*hello world
```

---

In `printf()`, the `*` modifier to the conversion specifier is a way of supplying a field width or precision (or both) from arguments to the `printf()` call (rather than a hard coded number straight into the format string itself). So:

```
char *s="hello world";
int i=7;
printf("%.*s\n", i, s);
```

Will print the output:

```
hello w
```

The `*` in this case is the precision, since it follows the decimal point. For a string, this means the maximum number of characters from the string that will be printed.